# Trying to create a text-based login/sign up in python

Tags: python, python-3.x

No matter what I do, the code always reverts to the first *username or password is incorrect* statement. Here is the code:

```
lines = []
usernames = []
passwords = []
foundU = False
foundP = False
counter = 0
with open("login_project/logins.txt", "r+") as f:
    lines = f.readlines()
    f.close()

for element in lines:
    if counter % 2 == 0:
        usernames.append(element.strip())
    else:
        passwords.append(element.strip())
    counter += 1

def Search(lista, val, found):
    for i in range(0, len(lista)):
        if lista[i] == val:
            found = True
        else:
            pass
    return found

def login():
    username = input("Please enter your username: ")
    password = input("Please enter your password: ")
    Search(usernames, username, foundU)
    Search(passwords, password, foundP)
    if foundU == False or foundP == False:
        print("Username or password is incorrect")
    elif usernames.index(username) != passwords.index(password):
        print("Username or password is incorrect 2")
    else:
        print("Login succesful")

login()
```

The error occurs here mainly:

```
    if foundU == False or foundP == False:
        print("Username or password is incorrect")
    elif usernames.index(username) != passwords.index(password):
        print("Username or password is incorrect 2")
    else:
        print("Login succesful")
```

Would appreciate any help, only doing this at a GCSE level so I am still quite a begginer.

edit: also in the file is just:

```
User01
password
User02
password2
```

Comment: that is pretty good for a noob, and you did a nice job parsing the text file into two lists and checking for matching indices.  In summary, you are not assigning the return value of Search and thus it is lost- that is why you get the error.  Also, there is the issue of global (available throughout the program file) vs. local (exists only in the function).  I think you are very close to fixing the bug, and perhaps the answer posted below will help with your understanding.  Best of luck with Python- it's a great language!

Answer (score 0):

`Search` never changes `foundU` or `foundP`. Passing a variable to a function in Python doesn't necessarily mean that if you change the variable in the function, that it will change the original. You just need to do something like `foundU = Search(usernames, username)`. In addition, since `foundU` and `foundP` are globals, if you want to change their values globally, you have to declare them as globals:

```
...
def login():
    global foundU
    global foundP
    username = input("Please enter your username: ")
    password = input("Please enter your password: ")
    foundU = Search(usernames, username, foundU)
    foundP = Search(passwords, password, foundP)
...
```

However, `Search` is unnecessary, since Python's `in` operator does what you want. So you could just do:

```
foundU = username in usernames
foundP = password in passwords
```

Answer (score 0):

You have global variables foundU and foundP - these are not being modified inside your function when you call search.  Even if they were - your function would simply create a local copy unless you "tell" your code not to.

```
def login():
    global foundU  # to modify a global from local scope
    global foundP
    username = input("Please enter your username: ")
    password = input("Please enter your password: ")
    # set var using returned val from call to function
    foundU = Search(usernames, username, foundU)  
    foundP = Search(passwords, password, foundP)
```

If you were to have your login routine return an indicator of login (a bool perhaps) to where it is called, you may be better to remove the global vars and just use two locals.

After posting this, I noticed another problem with using the search function as implemented, and with using the "in" keyword as suggested.. neither will ensure that the username and password match... any username with any password would get authenticated.... so, here is a version that seems to work but it does not need the global vars

```
lines = []
usernames = []
passwords = []
counter = 0
with open("login_project/logins.txt", "r+") as f:
    lines = f.readlines()
    f.close()

# ensure there is a password for each user
assert len(usernames) == len(passwords), "Error reading file"

for element in lines:
    if counter % 2 == 0:
        usernames.append(element.strip())
    else:
        passwords.append(element.strip())
    counter += 1

def validate(u_name, password):
    '''Check that user and p/w are at same indices
       in each of the lists'''
    for i in range(0, len(usernames)):
        if usernames[i] == u_name:
            if passwords[i] == password:
                return True
    return False

def login():
    username = input("Please enter your username: ")
    password = input("Please enter your password: ")
    found = validate(username, password)
    if found:
        print("Login successful")
        return True
    else:
        print("Username or password is incorrect")
        return False
        

login()
```

A better data structure may be to use a dict for usernames (keys) and passwords(values) and write these to a json file which looks very similar with the caveat that all the data is stored as str.

Comment: That doesn't work at all. `Search` still isn't changing `foundU` or `foundP`. `Search` would have to have `global foundU` and `global foundP` in it, and it would have to know which one to change based on the arguments passed in. Which just seems unnecessarily complicated.

Comment: @RandomDavis I didn't see your post until afterwards... +1 for using the "in" keyword and avoiding the search altogether.  The prob I saw was the bools not being modified.  Now that I look again, there are more probs than I thought...

Comment: Yeah looks good now, you were just missing the `foundU = ...` and such.

Comment: I had the assignment statements, but your comment got me looking more at the Search as well... the in keyword would not verify position in list... maybe a solution using the find method and matching indices, but then there is the issue of checking and if "not found" the -1 could be marched so I suggest a different and simpler function to match the indices of the username and password, and eliminate the globals altogether. 
I still think a dict would be a more elegant solution but this is likely a reasonable solution for the method used with two lists.